# An existing vega-lite map suddenly seems very zoomed-in - what is happening?

Tags: format, topojson, vega-lite

I have a map with an older topojson format that once worked with Vega-Lite. Now we only see a purple square in [this editor gist.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/44f556718d6f1eb474170cc25e55988c/spec.json)

I've rebuilt the map with the same code but updated topojson in the vega editor and [saved as a gist here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/e74cfd776a72f6d6036d8085cfd16604/spec.json).

With the new vega release, it seems like I need my topojson files to be formatted differently, with the arcs first, like the mapshaper.org export output. Why is this? It's broken several existing web maps, and took me a few hours to figure out. Seems like I can fix it with a workflow change, but I am curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topojson data follows the left-hand rule for projected data (clockwise orientation for outer rings and counter- clockwise for interior rings), where the data in your topojson file is structured according the right-hand rule (counter-clockwise for outer rings and clockwise for interior rings). The order of your polygons seems negligible, but it defines which part is ‘inside’ and ‘outside’ the polgygons.

You can do two things:

1. Do not use a geographic projection, but the cartesian-like `identity` projection.
2. Force your source data into the right order.

---

*Example for 1:*

`"projection": {"type": "identity", "reflectY": true},`

[see Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-4gQRIfIOVCQkDIIww+PnF461wwJCJgH1QRfBGoAtwIuZHRqAxkE46aEmHG+c1qLS2vROl1u071rQARwGtjoI1Ipmgg0uoC4iBeOFCOHelqL7x1smnOJqZtsWlWQkzxwBdHeaFkDEEgj+Si6VENROYgFy0ZQYBENUQEAtgNQAdXUTQcVAwRXTQABGIsXE2TsIVAScti0D12S9LlTATF5ZDRAxBjVAizSI9BZwdZ00MXSjV3XL49C+bcflDf5QGrWscU49BGwgZtEz7WQByHEdNhqECwNQb9fyLWDgJxGxB1jeQxPlY50CxBgEEoEiOW9NQAF4bIAcgAYSQWQkCMNw4Htfh7TmEtMBLG8IHs0xUPQ9AahcoN-xgwE4LgRCNBgFT2LQABmP4BJ+IA)

[image]

---

*Example for 2:*

Use MapShaper or Python to force your data in the right order. Here an example using Python

```
import topojson as tp
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nycehs/NeighborhoodReports/master/visualizations/json/UHF42.topo_old.json')
tp.Topology(gdf).to_json('UHF42.topo_new.json')
```

[see Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-YsgUafWxaLpCODeTCmD6YYdoWQMQSCPZKGovaUTYg1rTKGAiUcgA93OAAdXUminJ8E5rQAEZJS42MmaKng6W5boFahLEqSq71loshogYLKjiWGqTnqBrVq+taRo2zZrm2Xg7F6+ygKG4ZThh0auHGUaZrI2a5vmP6jMep6oFuO6SjeR5TjYOYfEMJFfCu6ClAwCCUM8rzGB8XyUAA4gAogA8riACCACyskALzqQA5AAUkgyA0FASBaaYL5vugoxILI7p7tehy3g+GgwIxaFoAAzHseE7EAA)

[image]

---

I wrote a bit about it before for Altair and Python Topojson

- https://mattijn.github.io/topojson/example/settings-tuning.html#winding_order
- https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#winding-order

And Mike Bostock for D3

- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a7bdfeb041e850799a8d3dce4d8c50c8

Comment: This is an excellent and comprehensive answer, serves as a great reference for me and my team, and also really improves my understanding of topojson. I'll be using the python snippet to re-wind all my NYC topojson now... and thanks for introducing me to the identity projection, which will be very useful for state-plane work. Only thing I'm still unclear on is what prompted the change (the old right-hand rule topojson worked before...) but perhaps just a change to enforce consistency?

Comment: You’re welcome, but no idea about the change. As far as I know this *always* has been like this for topojson-structured input data.. Anyway, happy mapping!